# CSS not working when I add PHP code in a form

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Screenshot of the form without PHP:

[image: Screenshot before adding PHP code]

When I add following PHP code:

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <label for="">Distributor Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="DisPrice" placeholder="Distributor Price" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <label for="">Brand Name</label>
    <select name="car_id" id="car_id" class="form-control-label" >
    <?php
    $list = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `vehicle_registration` where `status`='0'");
    while ($row_ah = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list)) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_ah['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_ah['car_no']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <label for="">Description (use for ||| new Line)</label>
    <textarea name="Description" class="form-control" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

After that my form looks like this:

[image: Screenshot after adding PHP code]

Some CSS Logics still works but still show me the same issue.

Comment: Can you share what you see in your inspect element after you apply the changes?

Comment: We can't inspect pictures, Vikrant. Please post the output (HTML) of the form without php and the output with php. If you look close to the differences, you'll probably figure out what's wrong yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect the HTML page using the inspect tools.
The error might be displayed there..
It could be from `$conn` variable.